# Adding extra space around active item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

If you take a look at this:

https://jsfiddle.net/h8kmove5/27/

Say you click on 9 at the bottom. it displays 8 9 10. I am just trying to add a little extra space to the left and right of 9. Or any other active item for that matter. So that, for example, the right half of 8 and the left half of 10 are visible?

```
#sync1 .synced .item {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you mean...

Comment: It is just basically increasing the white space to the left and right of the middle item?

Answer (score 0):

I have added `active` class to active `owl-item` of `#sync1` using following `js`.

```
$("#sync1")
  .find(".owl-item")
  .removeClass("active")
  .eq(current+1)
  .addClass("active")
```

And use following `css` to add extra space around active item.

```
#sync1 .active {
    margin:0 50px;
}

#sync1 .owl-wrapper {
    margin-left: -50px;
}
```

#### [UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/azim101/h8kmove5/102/)

Comment: That doesn't work because it is shortening the width of the items when I increase the second margin value?

Answer (score 0):

I tried something. The way you had added  class 'synced' for '#sync2', I added the same for '#sync1'.

```
var current = this.currentItem;
console.log(current)
 $("#sync1")
  .find(".owl-item")
  .removeClass("synced")
  .eq(current+1)
  .addClass("synced")
```

And added margin to that synced element.

```
#sync1 .synced{margin:0 10px 0 10px;}
```

Check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thomas014/pnbe4gph/) here